# Aparecen varios errores al ejecutar

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de realizar una serie de palabras que van de arriban y bajan hasta cierto punto una a una cada cierto tiempo y que regresan a su estado inicial.

Pero no se ejecuta, pero cuando cambio la variable j por  un numero (En caso 1) ejecuta el código, pero no en todos los elementos, además me salen muchos errores como:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at slider.js:86

---

```
 const palabras = function (){
        setTimeout(function(){
    palabra1[j].style.transform = "translateY(0px)";
},1000)
setTimeout(function(){
    palabra2[j].style.transform = "translateY(0px)";
},1500)
setTimeout(function(){
    palabra3[j].style.transform = "translateY(0px)";
},2000)
setTimeout(function(){
    palabra1[j].style.opacity ="0";
    palabra2[j].style.opacity ="0";
    palabra3[j].style.opacity ="0";
    
},4500)
setTimeout(function(){
    palabra1[j].style.transform = "translateY(-300px)";
    palabra2[j].style.transform = "translateY(-300px)";
    palabra3[j].style.transform = "translateY(-300px)";

} ,intervalo)
setTimeout(function(){
    palabra1[j].style.opacity ="1";
    palabra2[j].style.opacity ="1";
    palabra3[j].style.opacity ="1";
},5500) 


}


for(var j = 0; j < palabra1.length; j++){
setInterval(function(){
    


},intervalo)
for(var j = 0; j < palabra2.length; j++){
    setInterval(function(){

        palabras();

},intervalo)

  }
    for(var j = 0; j < palabra3.length; j++){
setInterval(function(){
    
    palabras();

},intervalo)

}
```

---

Comment: ¿Cómo ejecutas la función `palabras()`? ¿Probaste agregando `j` como parámetro de la función? Porque esa variable no existe.

Comment: Disculpa amigo, copie el código de una pregunta que había hecho de un pregunta anterior, acabo de corregirlo, actualmente la función palabras() es una constante

Comment: Asignar una función anónima a una constante no afecta la forma en que trabaja y, definitivamente, es muy mala idea usar `setInterval()` dentro de ciclos, debería ser `setTimeout()` y **proporcionar la variable que no existe**.

Comment: ¿Por que es mala idea usar setInterval() dentro de un ciclo?,

Comment: Porque `setInterval()` va a ejecutarse automáticamente cada que pasa el tiempo especificado, sin que tengas que volver a llamarlo y, además, lo estás combinando con los `setTimeout()` dentro de la función. No he analizado todo el código, pero parece que el resultado va a ser completamente inesperado.